# Запись в сокет выдает ошибку unable to write to socket: no address was supplied

Tags: php, websocket

Файл server.php

```
<?php
   /* < < < < < < < < -< MODULES >- > > > > > > > > */
   require_once("classes/chat.php");
   $chat = new Chat();
   $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

   /* < < < < < < < < -< VARIABLES >- > > > > > > > */
   $url = 'localhost/chat';
   $port = 8091;
   $ip = 0;

   /* < < < < < < < < -< CONNECTED >- > > > > > > > */
   socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
   socket_bind($socket, $ip, $port);
   socket_listen($socket);

   $clientSocketArray = array($socket);
   $null = null;

   while(true) {
      $newSocketArray = $clientSocketArray;
      socket_select($newSocketArray, $null, $null, 0, 10);

      if(in_array($socket, $newSocketArray)) {
         $newSocket = socket_accept($socket);
         $clientSocketArray[] = $newSocket;

         $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
         $chat -> sendHeaders($header, $newSocket, $url, $port);

         socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
         $connectionACK = $chat -> newConnectionACK($client_ip_address);
         $chat -> send($connectionACK, $clientSocketArray);
      }
   }

   /* < < < < < < < -< CLOSE-CONNECT >- > > > > > > */
   socket_close($socket);
?>
```

файл chat.php

```
<?php
    class Chat {
       /*<-->*/
       public function sendHeaders($headersText, $newSocket, $host, $port) {
          $headers = array();
          $tmpLine = preg_split("/\r\n/", $headersText);

          foreach($tmpLine as $line) {
             $line = rtrim($line);
             if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches)) {
                $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
             }
          }

          $key = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
          $sKey = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($key.'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));

          $strHeadr = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" .
             "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
             "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
             "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
             "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/chat/server.php\r\n" .
             "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $sKey\r\n\r\n"
          ;

          socket_write($newSocket, $strHeadr, strlen($strHeadr));
       }
       /*<-->*/
       public function newConnectionACK($client_ip_address) {
          $message = "New client $client_ip_address connected";
          $messageArray = [
             "text" => $message,
             "type" => "newConnectionACK"
          ];
          $ack = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
          return $ack;
       }
       /*<-->*/
       public function seal($socketData) {
          $b1 = 0x81;
          $lenght = strlen($socketData);
          $text = "";

          if($lenght <= 125) {
             $text = pack('CC', $b1, $lenght);
          } else if($lenght > 125 && $lenght < 65536) {
             $text = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $lenght);
          } else if($lenght > 65535) {
             $text = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $lenght);
          }
          return $text.$socketData;
       }
       /*<-->*/
       public function send($message, $clientSocketArray) {

          $messageLenght = strlen($message);

          foreach($clientSocketArray as $clientSocket) {
             socket_write($clientSocket, $message, $messageLenght);
          }
          var_export( $clientSocketArray );
          return true;
       }
       /*<-->*/
    }
```

Это все выдает ошибку:
Warning: socket_write(): unable to write to socket [10057]: ������ �� �������� ��� ��������� ������  (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.
 in D::way:\localhost\chat\classes\chat.php on line 60

Так же при выводе всех подключений - выдает сразу 2 подключения:
array (
  0 => NULL,
  1 => NULL,
)